# How to load images downloaded via SDWebImage into a view controller when download is complete?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I have an array of 10 URLs that are linked to images of my website.

I'm using SDWebImages for async image downloading and a for loop to run thru the array of URLs. But the code would just run thru the For-loop before the first image can be downloaded. Therefore, the rest of the images never gets downloaded and the new view controller is never displayed

How can I allow the code to run thru the for-loop, and once an image has been downloaded, it pops up a view controller and gets updated whenever a new image is downloaded.

Here's my code:

```
NewViewController *vc = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
NavigationController *navigationController = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

for (NSString *url in urls) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post-imagePlaceholder"]
                     completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                             item.image = image;

                             [self.images addObject:item];
                             vc.results = self.images;
                            ;
                         }
    }];
}

[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil]
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues jump out at me:

1. You are creating an new set of image views, but never adding them to any view (e.g. `addSubView`).
2. Furthermore, If these views are in `NewViewController`, you should have that controller perform the `setImageWithURL` calls (e.g. in it's `viewDidLoad`), not the current view controller. The current view controller should simply pass the `urls` array to the `NewViewController`.
3. Finally, you are trying to populate an array with the images, but

   - The way you've written this, I would guess that you're expecting that `self.images` will be populated before the new view controller appears. But it won't, because this `completed` block happens asynchronously.
   - You generally shouldn't be populating an array of images anyway, because images require immense amount of memory. If the number of images in your app grows, you'll run across memory warnings. We generally should not maintaining arrays of URLs and let `SDWebImage` do the cacheing to efficiently retrieve the images.

So, the current view controller should just pass the `urls` array, and the `viewDidLoad` of `NewViewController` could iterate through those, either (a) finding the appropriate existing image views' `IBOutlet` references and call `setImageWithURL`; or (b) create a new `UIImageView`, set their respective `image` and `frame`/constraints and add that image view to the new view controller's view. But do not create any `images` array.

If not all of the image views are visible at one time, the above approach should be further refined (to only load the image for the visible image views). But hopefully the above answers the immediate question.

Comment: thanks. You're right on point 3.1. I thought it would, but every time it pops up a NewViewController that is empty. My NewViewController is a UITableView that displays the rows of the images downloaded. I shall try passing URLs array instead of images. Thanks!

Comment: @Scott If you're using a `UITableView`, then this is even easier. Just use `setImageWithURL` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. No `images` array, no manual creation of `UIImageView` objects in `viewDidLoad`, etc. Easy as can be. These `UIImageView` categories are perfect for combining with table views.

Comment: Each of those cell needs to display 3 images. Also, I would need to check to ensure that the images are good, i.e. dimensions greater than 100 x 100. I need to download and store the images else where and analyse then load the images into the cell...

Comment: @Scott That's fine. But I'd still contend that (a) you can do that in your `completed` block; (b) this `setImageWithURL` logic still belongs at the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (or frankly, you're approaching a level of complexity that I'd put it in a `UITableViewCell` subclass); and (c) you never want to be in the business of maintaining arrays of `UIImage` objects (perhaps `NSCache` if you want to do some optimization, but never `NSMutableArray`).