# iOS: SDWebImageManager not caching image

Tags: objective-c, caching, uiimageview, slideshow, sdwebimage

I'm creating a slideshow using `UIImageView`, and the image links are in an array , so while I was at it, I learned that `SDWebImageManager` lets hit the URLs once only and then it caches the images for later use.

But what I'm monitoring in my app is that the 1st image is cached, I believe, but the 2nd image URL is always being hit.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arry addObject:@"http://adjingo.2cimple.com/content/151/Image/6291.jpg"];
    [arry addObject:@"http://adjingo.2cimple.com/content/151/Image/6290.jpg"];

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[arry objectAtIndex:0]];

    __block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    __weak UIImageView *weakImageView = self.imageView;
    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    [manager downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                      options:0
                     progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                         // progression tracking code
                         if (!activityIndicator) {
                             [weakImageView addSubview:activityIndicator = [UIActivityIndicatorView.alloc initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray]];
                             //activityIndicator.center = self.imageView.center;
                             [activityIndicator startAnimating];
                         }
                     }
                    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                        if (image) {
                            // do something with image
                            [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                            activityIndicator = nil;
                            [self.imageView setImage:image];
                        }
                    }];

//Timer to do slideshow for images
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0
                                             target: self
                                           selector: @selector(handleTimer:)
                                           userInfo: nil
                                            repeats: YES];
}
```

Here's the `handleTimer` code, to reload image in image view, every 5 seconds:

```
-(void) handleTimer: (NSTimer *) timer {

        currentImage++;
        if ( currentImage >= arry.count )
            currentImage = 0;

        __block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
        __weak UIImageView *weakImageView = self.imageView;
        SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
        [manager downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                      options:0
                     progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                         // progression tracking code
                         if (!activityIndicator) {
                             [weakImageView addSubview:activityIndicator = [UIActivityIndicatorView.alloc initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray]];
                             //activityIndicator.center = self.imageView.center;
                             [activityIndicator startAnimating];
                         }
                     }
                    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                        if (image) {
                            // do something with image
                            [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                            activityIndicator = nil;
                            [self.imageView setImage:image];
                        }
                    }];
}
```

Here's where I monitor the network usage:
[image]

Please guide me if I have used the `SDWebImageManager`wrongly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

my mother language is Chinese,not English.Maybe I cannot express my thought clearly,while I will try my best to tell my idea.if I confuse you , I feel sorry.

I cannot pod SDWebimage because my country blocks google sometimes,so I cannot reproduce your scenarios.While I still give your some advice which may help you

First of all, your gave us little context.Maybe you can post more information about member variables and properties.When I copy your code to the Xcode.I need add them by myself.

Second,you mean when you use
    `NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[arry objectAtIndex:1]];,`

sdwebimage hits urls every time , not use cache URLs? you can get the image source by NSLog the  cacheType.

```
completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {  
                      if (image) {                                                    
                            NSLog(@"%d",cacheType);
                          [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                          activityIndicator = nil;
                          [self.imageView setImage:image];
                     }
                  }];`
```

SDImageCacheTypeNone means image comes from network.

SDImageCacheTypeDisk means image comes from disk.

SDImageCacheTypeMemory means image comes from Memory.

Third,because the `downloadWithURL:options:completed:` is excuted not on the main thread. I doubt the sequence is the same with your thought.