# How to add UIImage object into NSMutableArray in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to add `UIImage` objects into an array but they are not being added. Please help

my code:

```
imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
arry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[arry addObject:@"http://adjingo.2cimple.com/content/151/Image/6291.jpg"];
[arry addObject:@"http://adjingo.2cimple.com/content/151/Image/6290.jpg"];

//Fetch images from web and store in another array
for (int i=0; i<[arry count]; i++)
{
    NSString *string=[arry objectAtIndex:i];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if ( !error )
                           {
                               UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

                               //Store image in imageArray
                               [imageArray insertObject:image atIndex:i];

                           } else{

                           }
                       }];
}

NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[imageArray count]); //this line is always showing 0 as count
```

When I'm printing the `count` of the array containing `UIImage` objects, its showing **0**.

(I actually want to download images at once in array, then show it un `UIImageView` as slideshow).

Please guide me. Thank you!

Comment: You can first convert that image into NSData & can then add that data in array.

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh 1. Note that the received images *are* `NSData` objects. 2. There is no problem with saving the `NSImage` objects in an `NSMutableArray`, it is only the pointers that are in the array.

Comment: @zaph , Please check my comment to your answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems.

1. `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` does not allocate memory and items can not be added beyond the current size. `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:size]` does allocate the memory and objects can be inserted at any index up to and including the current size. See the `NSMutableArray` documentation.
2. Immediately after the `sendAsynchronousRequest` block no images have ben downloaded, that will happen as the downloads complete.
3. Starting a large number of downloads all at once can present performance problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would like to inform that there won't be any large numbers of downloads at once because 1. images will be of small sizes, 2. only 2 - 4 images will be there.
Secondly, I've also tried using `SDWebImageManager` but ran into a problem [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818813/ios-sdwebimagemanager-not-caching-image) , so I thought going this simpler way.

Can you elaborate a little on your 1st point?

And yes you're right about point # 2. But then where should I add them in my array?

Regards

Comment: WRT point 1, change the allocation method of `imageArray` to `arrayWithCapacity:`.  You are adding the images at a good point, it is just that they will be available at a later time. As they actually are received you can do something in the block, fire a notification or something based on your usage of them.